# get key or value from array to use in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I want to assign values from an array to a simple variable, my code is as follows :

```
$codeval = $_POST['code']; //can be Apple or Banana or Cat or Dog
$systemrefcode = array("a" => "Apple", "b" => "Banana", "C" => "Cat", "D" => "Dog");

foreach($systemrefcode as $code => $value) {
     if($codeval == $value){ //if Apple exists in array then assign code and use it further
        $codes = $code;//Assign code to codes to use in next step

     }
$selection = 'Your Selection is -'.$codes.'and its good.';
echo $selection;
```

When I check in console it shows no response. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure if it fixes it, but you are missing a double quote in `"D => "Dog"`. Try `"D" => "Dog"` and there is a closing `}` missing.

Comment: those are common mistakes, i did them in a hurry, but still after fixing that didn;t get what i wanted

Comment: What happens when you var_dump $codeval? If it doesn't match anything in your array, you won't get any output.

Comment: as far i can see they;re matching the array but i got no response.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the key of the wanted value with [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-search.php):

```
$array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');

$key = array_search('green', $array); // $key = 2;
```

So, for your code works, you can use like this:

```
$codeval = $_POST['code'];
$systemrefcode = array("a" => "Apple", "b" => "Banana", "C" => "Cat", "D" => "Dog");

$code = array_search($codeval, $systemrefcode);

$selection = 'Your Selection is - '.$code.' and its good.';
echo $selection;
```

**OBS.:**

1. *array_search()* will return *false* if value is not found;
2. *array_search()* is *case sensitive*, so if you have '*Apple*' in the array and search for '*apple*', it'll return *false*.

Comment: but when the requirement is dynamic,
like have the same array as you mentioned, and will do like this
$color = $_POST['color'];
$key = array_search($color, $array); 
$choose = 'You chose'.$key.'color code';
echo $choose;
Will i get the code of the respective color from array?

Comment: @BRAHMA array_search() returns the key of the searched value, so if the key is a color code, yes, you'll get the code of the respective color. But have in mind that array_serach() will return false if searched value is not in the array.

Comment: Did you run my code and checked? See nothing is coming.

Comment: @BRAHMA I edited the post to show you how you can use it in your code.

Comment: @BRAHMA what do you mean as "not working"? it's echoing nothing? are you having en error message? and also the code in this link is not the one I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

You could `break` out of the `foreach` when there is a match and echo the string afterwards.

```
$post = "1-Apple";
$codeval = explode('-', $post)[1];
$systemrefcode = array("a" => "Apple", "b" => "Banana", "C" => "Cat", "D" => "Dog");
$codes = "";

foreach ($systemrefcode as $code => $value) {
    if ($codeval === $value) { //if Apple exists in array then assign code and use it further
        $codes = $code;//Assign code to codes to use in next step
        break;
    }
}

if ($codes !== "") {
    $selection = 'Your Selection is -' . $codes . ' and its good.';
    echo $selection; // Your Selection is -a and its good.
} else {
    echo "codes is empty";
}
```

Comment: This is working since you assigned the value directly to $codeval, but in my case the value is coming to this php file via AJAX and using form serialize(), so do i need to do something special and again the value assigned to the $codeval is like (1-Apple, and i'm exploding it then assigning the 1st index to $codeval and then doing the rest), is there any modification to code, as per your suggestion?

Comment: @BRAHMA So you are doing something like https://3v4l.org/GK09a What exactly is missing?

Comment: In my case again its not working, will you please check this one https://3v4l.org/rhlil

Comment: @BRAHMA You are forgetting explode. Check https://3v4l.org/sYDar That will return an array from which you will get the second entry `[1]` which will be "Prepaid"

Answer (score 0):

You can flip the `$systemrefcode` array so that the values become keys and vice versa.

```
$coderefsystem = array_flip($systemrefcode);
$codes = $coderefsystem($codeval);
$selection = 'Your Selection is -'.$codes.'and its good.';
echo $selection;
```